# Kibana elasticsearch integration

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to install kibana + elasticsearch + fluentd. I have both elasticsearch and fluentd installed and working, but can't seem to get kibana to link to elasticsearch.

I'm using Kibana3, followed the installation instructions on the elasticsearch website.

Basically, download the Tar file, extract contents, change config.js Set the elasticsearch parameter to the fully qualified hostname of your Elasticsearch server. Copy the contents of the extracted directory to your webserver.

I have done all of that. I'm running ubuntu 12.04 with apache.
I copied the kibana files to the root of my /var/www folder, when i visit the site, there's a header
 {{dashboard.current.title}} with kibana logo.

What am I missing. My config.js file is as follows

```
define(['settings'],
function (Settings) {


  /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/2
   * === Parameters
   */
  return new Settings({

    /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
     * ==== elasticsearch
     *
     * The URL to your elasticsearch server. You almost certainly don't
     * want +http://localhost:9200+ here. Even if Kibana and Elasticsearch are on
     * the same host. By default this will attempt to reach ES at the same host you have
     * kibana installed on. You probably want to set it to the FQDN of your
     * elasticsearch host
     */
    elasticsearch: "http://"+window.location.myserver-fqdn+":9200",

    /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
     * ==== default_route
     *
     * This is the default landing page when you don't specify a dashboard to load. You can specify
     * files, scripts or saved dashboards here. For example, if you had saved a dashboard called
     * `WebLogs' to elasticsearch you might use:
     *
     * +default_route: '/dashboard/elasticsearch/WebLogs',+
     */
    default_route     : '/dashboard/file/default.json',

    /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
     * ==== kibana-int
     *
     * The default ES index to use for storing Kibana specific object
     * such as stored dashboards
     */
    kibana_index: "kibana-int",

    /** @scratch /configuration/config.js/5
     * ==== panel_name
     *
     * An array of panel modules available. Panels will only be loaded when they are defined in the
     * dashboard, but this list is used in the "add panel" interface.
     */
    panel_names: [
      'histogram',
      'map',
      'pie',
      'table',
      'filtering',
      'timepicker',
      'text',
      'hits',
      'column',
      'trends',
      'bettermap',
      'query',
      'terms',
      'stats',
      'sparklines'
    ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console from your developer tools?

Comment: Yes there was an error in the console, I was able to fix it. Thanks. the elastic search parameter was wrong. With both elasticsearch and kibana on the same server, the elastic parameter should not change from the default.

Comment: @AfDev, do you have this problem yet?

Comment: @kikicarbonell Whats your question? It was solved by pointing to my elasticsearch host, use the default if both(kibana & esearch) are installed on the same host

Comment: @AfDev, ok, I was only asking if you need help to solve this problem yet. You can post your solution as an answer below to help the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use kibana 3 with tomcat server. Just copy your kibana folder into webapps folder of tomcat.

- now start kibana with following link in your browser:   8080 is tomcat port.

  `http:localhost:8080/Kibana-folder-name`